# Offline Relational Database for Cross Mobile Platform

Tags: android, ios, relational-database, cross-platform, devextreme

I am developing a Cross Platform (Android & iOS) Mobile App which would be compiled and deployed natively. (APK for Android and IPA for iOS). So this App would execute on WebView on Mobile Devices.

I am using DevExtreme (product of DevExpress) to develop the Mobile App. So basically HTML5. CSS3 and JavaScript is used for Coding the App. Now, I require a Offline Relational Database to store data related to my App.

I know that the below mentioned are available for the above mentioned use case, but I do have problem with each of them and that I have mentioned below:

1. WebSQL/SQLite: Deprecated and No Longer supported.
2. IndexedDB: Do not support iOS Safari and not useful for me.
3. Sequel Sphere: I think this is just Browser related and would not run on WebView. (Confused)

I surfed a lot and I am not able to arrive at a proper decision. Can anybody help/ provide me with a proper solution that would suit my above mentioned requirement.

I need a Offline Relational Database that would run on Android and iOS Devices.

Comment: Who told SQLite is not longer supported?

Comment: Don't you want to use web-services in such as case ?

Comment: I want Offline Database and WebServices requires Internet. So not a Case to consider. :)